# Como especificar cada arquivo em 2 input file?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho 2 input file, um para selecionar a foto do perfil e o outro para escolher uma foto background. Cada foto tem dimensões diferentes e eu gero uma pré-visualização antes do usuário salvar.

Na foto do perfil, tudo certo. já na foto background, o JS gera a visualização, mas quando clico em salvar, não salva e acaba sumindo com a foto no perfil. Como eu especifico o arquivo de cada foto em files[]?

Já tentei colocar event como parâmetro da função e chamar event, event.target e nada funcionou.

Eis o meu código:

```html
<?php
require "conexao.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
$idu = $_SESSION ['idu'];
if (isset($_FILES['arquivo'])) {
   $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4));
   $novo_nome = md5(time()).$extensao;
   $diretorio = "uploads/";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);
   $sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE bancodados SET foto='$novo_nome' WHERE id='$idu'");
}
if (isset($_FILES['segundplano'])) {
   $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['segundplano']['name'], -4));
   $novo_nome = md5(time()).$extensao;
   $diretorio = "uploads/";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['segundplano']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);
   $sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE bancodados SET imagemfundo='$novo_nome' WHERE id='$idu'");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Editar Perfil</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/editar-perfil.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function visualizacao(){
   var target=document.getElementById("target");
   var file=perfil.arquivo.files[0];
   var reader= new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend=function (){
    target.src=reader.result;
    document.images['target'].width = 150;
   };
   if(file){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   } else {
    target.src="imagens/usuario.jpg";
   }
  }
  function panofundo(){
   var alvo=document.getElementById("ft-bg");
   var arq=background.segundplano.files[0];
   var reader= new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend=function (){
    alvo.src=reader.result;
    document.images['ft-bg'].height = 300;
   };
   if(arq){
    reader.readAsDataURL(arq);
   } else {
    alert("falha na leitura do arquivo");
    alvo.src="imagens/possib-conex.jpg";
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="painel">
  <a class="voltar" href="perfil.php?id=<?php echo $idu; ?>" title="Voltar"><img src="imagens/voltar.jpg" alt="Voltar"></a>
       <a class="sair" href="logout.php" title="Sair"><img src="imagens/sair.jpg" alt="Sair"></a> 
 </div>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="ftperfil">
   <h1>Foto do perfil</h1>
   <div id="foto">
    <?php require "query-idu.php"; ?>
    <figure>
        <img id="target" src="<?php echo $imagem; ?>" alt="Foto de Perfil" width="150"/>
    </figure>
   </div>
   <form name="perfil" action="editar-perfil.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label for="file">Escolher foto</label>
       <label for="salvarft">Salvar</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="arquivo" onchange="visualizacao()"/>
        <input id="salvarft" type="submit" value="Salvar"/>
       </form>
     </div>
     <div id="fundo">
      <h1>Imagem segundo plano</h1>
      <div id="bg">
    <?php require "query-idu.php"; ?>
    <figure>
        <img id="ft-bg" src="<?php echo $ftfundo; ?>" alt="Foto de Perfil" height= "300"/>
    </figure>
   </div>
      <form name="background" action="editar-perfil.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label class="img-bg" for="ftfundo">Escolher foto</label>
       <label class="img-bg" for="salvarft">Salvar</label>
       <input type="file" id="ftfundo" name="segundplano" onchange="panofundo()"/>
       <input id="salvarfundo" type="submit" value="Salvar"/>
   </form>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No caso, ambas as funções JS não podem ser files[0].

Comment: Tente alterar o nome da variável "file" em `var file=perfil.arquivo.files[0];`. Já existe um id "file" no `input` e isso pode estar gerando algum conflito.

Comment: Esse é um formulário só ? Se for porque está com das tag `form` ?

Comment: São dois formularios. Cada um com um input file.

Comment: Não está retornando nenhum erro ? Faz um `debug` em cada linha do PHP, exemplo: após o `if` coloque `var_dump($_FILES['arquivo']);` e assim por diante.

Comment: A questão é como selecionar as posições em files[]. Vc sabe se cada input gera um Array files[] ou se existe um só Arrau files[] e cada input vai inserindo um novo elemento no msm array ?

Comment: Eu tentei tbm em cada função verificar se files[0]=="undefined" mas nao funcionou. Em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications ele coloca this.files como parâmetro da função. Mas tentei usar this.files, this.files[0] e nada tbm

Comment: Já verificou se não está pegando o mesmo nome de arquivo?!

Comment: A pouco eu testei alert(file.name); em cada função e no 1 input mostra o nome correto do arquivo, e no 2 input mostra sempre 'arquivo'. 'arquivo' está no 1 input name='arquivo'. Mas no 2 input eu estou selecionando arq=background.segundoplano.files[0]; Como ele está pegando o nome do input 1??

Comment: Cada input está com nome correto. No 2 input eu esqueci de trocar file por arq. Como eu testo o PHP, pq dar echo ou var_dump não funciona já que o JS não está esperando nenhum resposta do servidor.